# Green's Theorem in the Plane with gradient

Tags: greens-theorem

**Problem**

Calculate $$\int_R \int \nabla^2 \big( x^3 - y^3  \big) ~dx~ dy$$ in the region bounded by $0 \leq y \leq x^2$ and $|x|\leq 2$.[1]

**My Attempt**

$$\nabla \big( x^3 - y^3  \big) = 3x^2 \hat{\bf{i}} - 3y^2 \hat{\bf{j}}$$
$$\nabla^2 \big( x^3 - y^3  \big) = 6x - 6y$$
$$ \int_{-2}^2 \Biggl[\int_0^{x^2}  6x - 6y ~dy \Biggl]dx$$
$$ \int_{-2}^2 \Biggl[  6xy - 3y^2 \Bigg|^{x^2}_0 \Biggl]dx$$
$$ \int_{-2}^2  6x^3 - 3x^2 ~dx$$
$$\tfrac{3}{2}x^4 - x^3\Bigg|_{-2}^2$$
$$ - (2)^3--(-2)^3$$
$$ - 8-8$$
$$ -16$$

So this looks pretty good to me; I can't find any problem. However, the answer in the back of the book says $-38.4$. Where is my mistake?

[1] From Kreyszig 10th edition problem 10.4.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a minor error in your calculation

$$\dots=\int_{-2}^{2}\left[6xy-3y^{2} \Bigg|_{y=0}^{y=x^{2}}\right]{\rm d}x=\int_{-2}^{2}\left(6x^{3}-3x^{\color{red}{4}}\right){\rm d}x=\frac{3}{2}x^{4}-\color{red}{\frac{3}{5}x^{5}}\Bigg|_{-2}^{2}=\color{red}{38.4}$$